# How to efficiently solve many linear programs with only one different constraint?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have a set of many similar linear programs (LP). All these LPs have the same objective function, and almost all constraints are the same. The only difference is for one linear constraint $f(x) = a_{i}$, where $a_{i}$ is a constant that changes from one LP to the next. Instead of solving each LP from scratch, is there a way I can use the information from the first LP problem to solve the other LPs more quickly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a change preserves dual feasibility, so you might consider applying the dual simplex method, with a warm start from the previous optimal basis.

Comment: Thanks! I thought warm start applied to MILP problems, not LP problems.
How would you implement this warm start with Python/Gurobi?

Comment: Glad to help.  There are warm start techniques for both MILP and LP.  Please mark my answer as accepted.